# Examples of random deployment in wireless sensors networks

Tags: applied-theory, applications

I have been doing some research and have found a lot of papers on the subject of random deployment in wireless sensor networks, but I haven't found a single example of its usage. Has it been used before? What could be a very concrete context in which it could be used?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One scenario that I've heard discussed is the idea that an airplane flies over a remote area and drops wireless sensors.  They fall somewhat randomly, and then need to establish a network amongst themselves.